# Using SWIG and the Python/C API to wrap a function which takes a Python list of C++ class instances

Tags: python, c++, swig

I want to wrap a C++ routine which takes in an array of class instances. I am having trouble getting this to work with SWIG and would appreciate any help that can be offered. I've tried to boil this issue down to its essence through a simple example.

The header `test.h` is defined as follows:

```
/* File test.h */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class Test {
  private:
    int my_value;
  public:
    Test(int value);
    void printTest();
};

void print_tests(int num_tests, Test** tests);
```

The implementation is defined in `test.cpp` below:

```
/* File test.cpp */
#include "test.h"

void print_tests(int num_tests, Test** tests) {
  for (int i=0; i < num_tests; i++)
    tests[i]->printTest();
}

Test::Test(int value) { 
  my_value = value; 
}

void Test::printTest() { 
  printf("my value is %d\n", my_value); 
}
```

I have written a SWIG interface file `test.i` to try to accommodate this routine so that I can pass in a Python list of `Test` class instances:

```
%module test

%{
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
  #include "test.h"
%}

%typemap(in) (int num_tests, Test** tests) {

  if (!PyList_Check($input)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Expected a Python list of Tests");
    return NULL;
  }

  $1 = PySequence_Length($input);  // num_tests
  $2 = (Test**) malloc(($1) * sizeof(Test*)); // tests

  /* Loop over tests */
  for (int i = 0; i < $1; i++) {
    /* Extract the value from the list at this location */
    PyObject* o = PyList_GetItem($input,i);
    $2[i] = (Test*) o;
  }
}

%include "test.h"
```

I wrap the routines and compile the SWIG-generated wrapper code, and link it as a shared library as follows:

```
> swig -python -c++ -o test_wrap.cpp test.i
> gcc -c test.cpp -o test.o -fpic -std=c++0x
> gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c test_wrap.cpp -o test_wrap.o -fpic -std=c++0x
> g++ test_wrap.o test.o -o _test.so -shared -Wl,-soname,_test.so
```

I then want to be able to do the following from within Python:

```
import test

test1 = test.Test(2)
test2 = test.Test(1)
test.print_tests([test1, test2, test1])
```

If I run this as a script `example.py`, however, I get the following output:

```
> python example.py 
my value is 3
my value is 2
my value is 3
```

Any ideas why I get `2` and `3` as output, rather than the `1` and `2` which were assigned to the `Test` class constructor? I believe this is an issue with my SWIG interface file passing in pointers to the SWIG `Test` class wrapper instances rather than the C++ `Test` class instances, but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An alternative to writing the c array typemap by hand could be to use the carray.i swig library: [link](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html#Library_carrays).

Comment: You will benefit tremendously if you write your code to use STL classes, or expose your code using `%inline`s that use STL classes. Post a question if you need help figuring out how to do that (note: you will not have any typemap to write and maintain!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in trying to directly cast the `PyObject o` to `Test *`.
We do not want the pointer of the `PyObject` which is a `SwigPyObject` but of `Test*` which is somewhere inside the `SwigPyObject`.
What you could do is to reuse `SWIG_ConvertPtr` (the way swig does it in the generated wrapper):

```
%typemap(in) (int num_tests, Test** tests) {

  if (!PyList_Check($input)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Expected a Python list of Tests");
    return NULL;
  }

  $1 = PySequence_Length($input);  // num_tests
  $2 = (Test**) malloc(($1) * sizeof(Test*)); // tests

  /* Loop over tests */
  for (int i = 0; i < $1; i++) {
    /* Extract the value from the list at this location */
    PyObject* o = PyList_GetItem($input,i);
    void *p1 = 0;
    SWIG_ConvertPtr(o, &p1,SWIGTYPE_p_Test, 0 |  0 );
    $2[i] = (Test*) p1;
  }
}
```

Comment: due to your very helpful answer here, I thought that you might also know the answer to a similar question of mine regarding SWIG posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308019/using-swig-and-the-python-c-api-to-wrap-a-function-which-returns-a-stdmap